# Python cant find class attribute

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Why is not `Factory.rdyq` visible to inherited classes?

bar.py

```
import Queue
import threading



class Factory:
    name = ""
    rdyQ = Queue.Queue()
    dispQ = Queue.Queue()

    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_count = 1
        self.worker_thread = None

    def worker(self): pass

    def initialize(self):
        for i in range(self.worker_count):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            self.worker_thread = t




    @staticmethod
    def joinQ():
        Factory.rdyQ.join()
        Factory.dispQ.join()
        return

    @staticmethod
    def getFactory(factory_name):
        if factory_name == "setup":
            return SetupFactory()
        elif factory_name == "dispatch":
            return DispatchFactory()
        elif factory_name == "complete":
            return CompleteFactory()
        else:
            return None

class SetupFactory(Factory):
    name = "setup"

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            try:
                item = Factory.rdyq.get(timeout=1)
                print "setup: %s" % item
                Factory.rdyq.task_done()

                Factory.dispQ.put(item)
            except Queue.Empty, msg:
                continue

class DispatchFactory(Factory):
    name = "dispatch"

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            try:
                item = Factory.dispQ.get(timeout=1)
                print "dispQ: %s" % item
                Factory.dispQ.task_done()

            except Queue.Empty, msg:
                continue

class CompleteFactory(Factory):
    name = "complete"

    def worker(self):
        for i in range(10):
            Factory.rdyq.put(i)
```

foo.py

```
import bar as df

setup = df.Factory.getFactory("setup")
dispatch = df.Factory.getFactory("dispatch")
complete = df.Factory.getFactory("complete")

setup.initialize()
dispatch.initialize()
complete.initialize()

df.Factory.joinQ()

setup.worker_thread.join()
dispatch.worker_thread.join()
complete.worker_thread.join()
```

> > python foo.py

```
  File "/u/bar.py", line 73, in worker
    Factory.rdyq.put(i)
AttributeError: class Factory has no attribute 'rdyq'
```

Comment: You need an instance for this. Try `Factory().rdyq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `classmethod` instead of a `staticmethod` for joinQ.

You also had a `rdyq` (bar.py last line) instead of the expected `rdyQ` and Python is case-sensitive.

bar.py

```
import Queue
import threading



class Factory:
    name = ""
    rdyQ = Queue.Queue()
    dispQ = Queue.Queue()

    def __init__(self):
        self.worker_count = 1
        self.worker_thread = None

    def worker(self): pass

    def initialize(self):
        for i in range(self.worker_count):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.worker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            self.worker_thread = t




    @classmethod
    def joinQ(cls):
        cls.rdyQ.join()
        cls.dispQ.join()
        return

    @staticmethod
    def getFactory(factory_name):
        if factory_name == "setup":
            return SetupFactory()
        elif factory_name == "dispatch":
            return DispatchFactory()
        elif factory_name == "complete":
            return CompleteFactory()
        else:
            return None

class SetupFactory(Factory):
    name = "setup"

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            try:
                item = Factory.rdyq.get(timeout=1)
                print "setup: %s" % item
                Factory.rdyq.task_done()

                Factory.dispQ.put(item)
            except Queue.Empty, msg:
                continue

class DispatchFactory(Factory):
    name = "dispatch"

    def worker(self):
        while True:
            try:
                item = Factory.dispQ.get(timeout=1)
                print "dispQ: %s" % item
                Factory.dispQ.task_done()

            except Queue.Empty, msg:
                continue

class CompleteFactory(Factory):
    name = "complete"

    def worker(self):
        for i in range(10):
            Factory.rdyQ.put(i)
```

Comment: might be off topic but why would one be static and the other be class method?

Comment: A class method has access to the class itself, while the static method is just a normal function wrapped inside an object for structure.

Comment: it's now giving me TypeError: joinQ() takes no arguments (1 given)
does classmethod gets argument from somehwere?

Comment: oh ok i see you put cls

Comment: Exactly, `cls` in classmethods works the same as `self` in methods, it gets passed by Python.

Answer (score 1):

Python variables and attributes are case sensitive, so "rdyq" is not the same as "rdyQ".

Answer (score 1):

You set the name with a capital q, so maybe this will fix it?

Factory.rdyQ.put(i)

I recommend using_underscores_for_variables as you avoid issues camelCase can cause.